# How to convert 2 signed 32 bit numbers to 64 bit in C

Tags: c, 64-bit

a and b are upper half and lower half of the same number. Now I have to save this number to a 64 bit register. 
lets say a = -1(Higher bytes) and b = -50. 
How can I do this ?

I am using the following which works for positive numbers.

```
int64_t c = (a);
c = (c<<32);
c+=b;
```

The above does not work for -ve numbers. How to do this ?

Edit: 
The above code for -ve numbers give a very large value for the -50. Basically what this means is that after the operation the "c" should have the value of -50, but it should be 64 bits. As upper half i.e. "a" is -1 and acts as the signed bit. The lower half has a -ve sign which makes it value very large due to the shifting operation.
I hope this is a little more clear.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Can you express mathematically what function you're hoping to accomplish? Or express it in terms of bit strings?

Comment: I repeat my previous comment. :P Are you trying to make `c` be the integer whose (two's complement) binary representation is the concatenation of the binary representations of `a` and `b` (both extended to be 32 binary digits long)?

Comment: @Hurkyl  thanks for your comments. Is the new edit clearer ?

Comment: did you mean c |= b on the last line?  Better question: what do you expect the answer to be if a = -1 and b = 50?

Comment: @clemej: Yes, that is his problem.  When he does addition, the 32nd bit will be zero and so he'll get a large negative number.

Comment: @Akash: Not really; you still don't explain how you actually want to combine numbers, just that you want these particular inputs to combine to become `-50`. Anyways, I'm giving up, and will leave `c += (uint32_t)b;`  as another possibility; maybe it will do what you want, maybe it won't, or maybe it will be right in your test cases but wrong when you are actually trying to use it with numbers that arise in a real program, I'll leave it to you to worry about it.

Comment: What is the type of `a` ?

Comment: note that `c << 32` causes undefined behaviour  (left-shift of negative value). To avoid undefined behaviour it'd be good to re-design your algorithm to work on unsigned integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean to do straight bitwise replacement without sign extension, then I think you want to replace

```
c += b;
```

in your code with

```
c |= (uint32_t)b;
```

For a = -1 and b = -50,this will make c = 0xffff.ffff.ffff.ffce

For a = -1 and b = 50, this will make c = 0xffff.ffff.0000.0032

For a = 1 and b = -50, this will make c = 0x0000.0001.ffff.ffce

For a = 1 and b = 50, this will make c = 0x0000.0001.0000.0032

Comment: Hat tip to @Hurkyl 's comment above that reminded me you may need a explicit cast to 32 bit to keep a negative 32-bit value from being sign extended to 64-bits before the bitwise or.

Comment: Thanks you so much this was perfect. I know my question was very very confusing. But your answer was spot on. I owe my hours and hours of time saved to you !!!!!

Comment: note: `+=` vs. `|=` makes no difference if the lower 32 bits of `c` are `0` and we are using 2's complement (as OP's code relies on anyway)